# Swift Array optional Type and subscripting (Beta 3)

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode6

I'm following the 2014 WWDC tutorial 408: Swift Playgrounds using XCode Beta 3 (30 minutes in).  The Swift syntax has changed since Beta 2.

```
var data = [27, 46, 96, 79, 56, 85, 45, 34, 2, 57, 29, 66, 99, 65, 66, 40, 40, 58, 87, 64]

func exchange<T>(data: [T], i: Int, j: Int) {
    let temp = data[i]
    data[i] = data[j]  // Fails with error '@lvalue $T8' is not identical to 'T'
    data[j] = temp     // Fails with error '@lvalue $T5' is not identical to 'T'
}

exchange(data, 0 , 2)
data
```

Why I can't modify a mutable integer array in this way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because subroutine parameters are implicitly defined with `let` hence, non mutable.  Try changing the declaration to:

```
func exchange<T>(inout data: [T], i: Int, j: Int) {
```

and the invocation to:

```
exchange(&date, 0, 2)
```

You can also use `var` but that would only allow the array to be modified within the subroutine.  The big change for beta 3 was to make arrays really pass by value instead of just kind of sorta pass by value some of the time, but not the rest.

Answer (score 2):

@David answer is correct, let me explain why: arrays (as well as dictionaries and strings) are  value types (structs) and not reference types. When a value type has to be passed to a function, a copy of it is created, and the function works on that copy.

By using the `inout` modifier, the original array is passed instead, so in that case it's possible to make changes on it.

Comment: I have a question. For example, I have an object which includes an array. And I pass this object through property of a UIViewController. What should I do to pass it as a reference?