# exchange array elements in Swift

Tags: swift

I wrote a function to exchange the array elements. But it returns error:
Playground execution failed: :21:5: error: '@lvalue $T8' is not identical to 'T'
    data[i] = data[j]
    ^
:22:5: error: '@lvalue $T5' is not identical to 'T'
    data[j] = temp
    ^

The code is as follows:

```
func exchange<T>(data: [T], i:Int, j:Int) {
    let temp:T = data[i]
    data[i] = data[j]
    data[j] = temp
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift Array optional Type and subscripting (Beta 3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710208/swift-array-optional-type-and-subscripting-beta-3)

Answer (score 8):

You can simply do:

```
swap(&data[i], &data[j])
```

If you want to write a generic function it will be this:

```
func exchange<T>(inout data: [T], i: Int, j: Int) {
    swap(&data[i], &data[j])
}

var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

exchange(&array, 0, 2)
array // ["c", "b", "a", "d"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` needs to be an `inout` parameter:

```
func exchange<T>(inout data: [T], i:Int, j:Int) {
    let temp:T = data[i]
    data[i] = data[j]
    data[j] = temp
}
```

You'd call it like:

```
var array = [1,2,3]
exchange(&array, 0, 2)
```

See [in-out parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_267) in the swift programming guide.