# Vector number allocation

Tags: arrays, swift, numbers

I'm trying to create a class including some operation of float, integer and long integer(Int64). But i cannot store the result of this operations in an array, i always see a compile error with a weird value (lvalue$T16 is not identical with Int64).

For example in this case :

```
func initializeWeights(w : [Int64], N : Int64)
    {
       for var i=0; i < Int(N)+1; i++
       {
          w[i] = Int64(((i + 1) % 4) * 10);
       }
    }
```

Here the error is placed in W[i] with the error message written above.
or here, same error :

```
func trainWeights(target : Int64, net : Int64, eta : Float, w : [Int64], x : [Int64], N : Int64)
{
    for var i=0; i < Int(N+1); i++
    {
        var deltaW = eta * Float(x[i] * (target - net));
        w[i] = w[i] + deltaW;
    }
}
```

I tried casting all the operation to match the vector format, or casting the elements of the operation which are different to Int64 like i did always in C/C++.

Thanks in advance for your advices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift Array optional Type and subscripting (Beta 3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710208/swift-array-optional-type-and-subscripting-beta-3)

Comment: As explained in the "duplicate", you have to declare `w` as *variable* parameter: `var w: [Int64]`.

Comment: @MartinR, I think he wants `inout` instead of `var` since he is initializing the array values and would want them to be modified outside of the function.

Comment: @vacawama: you are right, my fault.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the inout parameter save my life today.